# not able to update a oracle record in jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timeout

I have set oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout:1800000 (30 minutes).

i have a oracle employee record inserted from sql developer
insert into employee (id,user_name,start_date_time,end_date_time) values(1,'manjit',sysdate,sysdate);
commit;

Now I start a jdbc session update1.java and update the record above with employee id = 1.But I  dont commit nor rollback.The jvm is still running

i start a second jdbc session update2.java and update the same record again.It hangs.But then after 30 minutes I get this error Io exception: Socket read timed out

i start the  update2.java again and update the same record again.It again hangs.

What I found was as long update1.java is up and running I can never update the same record in update2.java !! Moment I kill update1.java session ,then update2.java goes ahead and is able to update the record!

I dont understand how does this work.
When I will be allowed to update the record in update2.java without killing update1.java

Comment: Why would you want another process to update a record that another process is still updating? you should not be doing that at all. Commit or rollback your first process then execute the next one, or a better one is create a transaction first then commit at the end.

Comment: Why are you retrying so hard to update the same record from the second session? What do you want to achieve? What do you expect the DBMS should do and if you were a DBMS what will you do in case of concurrent update?

Answer (score 0):

oracje.jdbc.readtimeout :
Read timeout while reading from the socket. Timeout is in milliseconds.

So it is not telling your system to stop waiting for a lock to be released. Your connection to the db is ok, but your second session is waiting on the first to commit/rollback.
If you want to work around such situation, do a select for update of the row, specifying 'for update wait ....'. Search 'for update' in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)